# Find a column1 value that has transacted in all distinct column2 values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to find all values in column1 that have transacted in all distinct values in column2. For ex:

[image]

From the above table we can identify the Fruitseller 'A' sells all the fruits.

Comment: Can you share the data frame code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape values by [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) first and then filter all index values if not `0` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['Fruitsellers'], df['Fruits'])

out = df1.index[df1.ne(0).all(axis=1)].tolist()
print (out)
['A']
```

Comment: One step: `pd.crosstab(df['Fruitsellers'], df['Fruits']).eq(1).all(1).loc[lambda x: x].index.tolist()`

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> df
   Fruitsellers     Fruits
0             A      Guava
1             A      Mango
2             B      Apple
3             C     Banana
4             D  Pineapple
5             A     Orange
6             B     Orange
7             C  Pineapple
8             A      Apple
9             A     Banana
10            A  Pineapple

>>> filetr_func = lambda x:sorted(x.Fruits.unique()) == sorted(df.Fruits.unique())
>>> (df
...  .groupby("Fruitsellers")
...  .apply(filetr_func)
...  .where(lambda x:x==True)
...  .dropna()
...  .index
...  .to_list()
... )

['A']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates().value_counts('Fruitsellers').eq(df['Fruits'].nunique()) \
      .loc[lambda x: x].index.tolist()

# Output:
['A']
```

Assume in the `Fruits` column at least one instance is present.

`drop_duplicates` is not mandatory if you are sure, you have not multiple same rows of (Fruitsellers, Fruits) like 2 x ('A', 'Mango').